# Communication between 2 Windows Forms applications

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have 2 windows form applications. 1st application interacts with database while the other application is aimed to communicate with the 1st application to interact with the database.
So how can I interact two applications with each other. Which tool should I use?

Comment: Why are they separate applications?  Why can't the second application access the database directly?  Are they running on the same machine? Is it a client/server setup?

Comment: It's for the demo that one application interacts with the other application and then the 1st application give its way to the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good example using WCF to communicate two processes:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Comment: down for me ---

Answer (score 3):

Another option is ZeroMQ C# binding:

http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:clr

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use WCF named pipes (net.pipe) the other option would be [Anonymous Pipes for Local Interprocess Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx)

Excerpt:

> Anonymous pipes offer less functionality than named pipes, but also
>   require less overhead. You can use anonymous pipes to make
>   interprocess communication on a local computer easier. You cannot use
>   anonymous pipes for communication over a network.

Answer (score 0):

Use WCF with netnamedpipe binding as @I4V recommends. Other alternatives are use Pipes, Remoting, or fileshare.